# How do they keep docking in "Star Trek: Enterprise"?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

I am re-watching *Enterprise*. Among all the weird history/lore stuff, one thing continues to bother me to no end.

How in the world, does the *Enterprise* constantly dock with darn near every ship out there?

They take the time to "translate" languages, to "lock on" the UT, to have crappy sensors that can't detect anything, weapons that may or may not be effective, and "not supposed to be sexy" near naked rub downs with nice gooie lotions for bio-contamination. However if they want to dock, it doesn't matter if they're an ally, a totally different life form, or openly hostile force, that docking port works 100% of the time.

Is there any reason, in universe, for this? Any random ideas, other than they just didn't think about it, any situations where the docking port didn't work?

Comment: It's called a universal fitting

Comment: Asked and (kinda) answered on another stack: [How were docking ports of Enterprise compatible universally?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10521/how-were-docking-ports-of-enterprise-compatible-universally)

Comment: I'm sure there's a better (or at least more canonical) answer lurking in one of the manuals. I'd be willing to bet that it's "*Starships docks use a mix of suction and magnetic to create a tight seals...etc*"

Comment: I agree with @user7812. It's likely a suction collar that can create a firm, tight seal, allowing cutting into the hull if necessary. In the re-imagined BSG series, they had universal "seal" style docking collars that could do the same thing. Form an air-tight seal anywhere on an opposing hull either for rescue, or cutting-in for invasion.